# Windows 10 secondary monitors task bars not hiding

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

My problem is the opposite of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/948074/557421). The task bar is auto hiding on my primary monitor just fine but it doesn't hide on my secondary monitors. Restarting didn't solve the problem. What is even weirder is I turned the auto-hide feature off and then back on the task bar on my left monitor stays up but it gets covered by a maximized window, the middle (primary) monitor auto hides as expected, and the right monitor task bar stays up and on top of a maximized window.

---

I'm currently running `Windows 10 Pro, Version 1511, Build 10586.104`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I cannot replicate this issue, someone with an [identical problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3c9oq0/windows_10_second_monitor_taskbar_doesnt_autohide/) shared their work around:

> I have found that if I do not have the search icon on the taskbar then
>   it will not auto-hide on the second monitor. Right click taskbar and
>   Search>Show search icon and then both taskbars will hide normally.

"Search" doesn't appear when I right click on the Taskbar, I must right click on the System Tray to get this option.

Comment: Well that is **really** annoying. When I showed the Cortana search box like you said and/or the Cortana icon the auto-hide feature worked. That irks me because I have no interest in the Cortana feature, and would much rather have it hidden. I've given you an up-vote and if no one else finds a better work around in the next few days I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: What build are you on? I'm on 10586.71 and can't replicate the issue

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1511, Build 10586.104

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but if you turn off "Show taskbar on all displays", you get around this issue, too (I don't need or want the taskbar everywhere).

[image: Taskbar and Start Menu Properties]

Comment: [the option on Windows 10 is different](https://superuser.com/a/1162606/241386)

Comment: @phuclv - funny, I took that screenshot in Windows 10 ‍♂️

Comment: probably because you took it too long ago. Nowadays right clicking on the taskbar > properties won't give you that dialog anymore and will show you the settings app instead

Comment: @phuclv - dunno. But it *was* taken on a Win10 box :)