# Show corresponding icons for each monitor on task bar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I'm working with several monitors in Windows 10.

When I have one software window in particular monitor, its task bar icon appears on all monitors. I would like to see MS Word icon only on monitor that has its window.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with the multi-monitor setup but the multiple desktop setup does have this option. When starting your program in another desktop (CTRL+WIN+right and start program) the icon isn't visible when you switch back (CTRL+WIN+left). There are some settings under `All settings > System > Multitasking > Virtual desktops`.

Comment: have you set the setting from my answer? Does it work the way you want it?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

[In the settings app](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3899-taskbar-hide-show-multiple-displays-windows-10-a.html) under the taskbar options, set the option `Show Taskbar button` under `Personalization`->`Taskbar` to "taskbar where window is open"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have personally tried two options:

#### DisplayFusion

DisplayFusion is a paid program with lots of features for multiple monitors on Windows.
https://www.displayfusion.com/

#### Dual Monitor Taskbar

Dual Monitor Taskbar is a freeware program that is much simpler and might do the trick - it splits the programs per monitor.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/

Answer (score 0):

if you change the "Show taskbar Buttons on" dropdown to "Main taskbar and taskbar where window is open" this will do close to what your asking, just that your main monitor will contain all icons. This is found in multiple displays under taskbar settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I used Realtime Soft UltraMon when I had Windows 7.

I hope it will work with Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/a/5330) paying particular attention to the items in `bold`. After doing so, please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1349360/edit) so it follows the guidelines. It might also be a good idea to take the [Tour] and read the [Ask] and [Answer] pages to learn how this site works.

Answer (score -3):

I doubt Windows provides such option, but you can use 3rd party tool, "Fences" for sorting out your icons.

You can check and download a 30-day trial from [here](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/).